# C linked list can't properly add data to list

Tags: c

Bit of a lengthy question so please bear with me. I am trying to create a doubly linked list in C using a dummy node as the head. For whatever reason, however, the list only saves the last node I read into it, and links the prev node pointer and the next node pointer to that last node, so if I try and iterate over the list, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Here is my node header file and C file. The linked list implementation isn't meant to be a full linked list implementation, so I only included the functions I need:

node.h:

```
#ifndef _node_h
#define _node_h

#include "task_block.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
  task_block_type *data;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
}node_t;

node_t *node_new(task_block_type *data);
void add(node_t *new, node_t *head);
#endif
```

node.c:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "task_block.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

node_t *node_new(task_block_type *data) {
  node_t *node = NULL;

  node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  node->data = data;
  node->next = NULL;
  node->prev = NULL;

  return node;
}

void add(node_t *new, node_t *head) {
  node_t *current = head;

  if (head->next == NULL) {
    head->next = new;
    head->next->prev = head;
    return;
  }

  while(current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
  }

  current->next = new;
  current->next->prev = current;

  return;
}
```

And finally, the code that is messing up from main.c:

```
    while (j < numTasks) {
      if (tasks[j].taskID == currentID) {
    *newTask = *task_block_new(tasks[j].taskID, tasks[j].period);
    newTask->startTime = starts[i];
    newTask->deadline = deadlines[i];
    newTask->executionTime = executions[i];
    *nodeNew = *node_new(newTask);
    add(nodeNew, eventQueue);
      }
```

I have already tested that my new task_block_type get the correct data form the text file and that the new node I create is initialized properly with the task block. Once I read it into my list with add(), however, it messes up. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been trying to fix this problem for several hours now and still haven't found a solution

EDIT:

self contained example:
*node_new is meant to be a constructer for my node objects and is supposed to return a pointer to a node object. So for example, say instead of having a node which contains the task_block_type as above, I have one that contains an int. If I wanted to initialize it with a value of 5, I would call

*newNode = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
*newNode = *node_new(5);

Hope that helps

Comment: Show a SSCCE please.

Comment: @EdHeal depends on his compiler

Comment: This is C, `new` is a valid variable name.

Comment: This is a leak: `*node_new(newTask);` Try a simpler example first.

Comment: Ok I cleaned up the post so its a bit clearer sorry about that. @2501 Do you mean a memory leak? As I mentioned in the post, I tested to see if the new nodes were initialized properly and I was able to access data from my task block through the new nodes

Comment: I have no idea what `nodeNew` is, and it is being dereferenced, possibly not a good idea. Present a *self-contained* example.

Comment: @2501 I added something hopefully that helps

Comment: @2501 also why would "dereferencing" my node_new funtion be aproblem? I thought that was how you return pointers from functions?

Comment: You need to make a SSCCE. Period.

Comment: @Nick Your function returns a pointer to allocated memory that _you are responsible for `free()`ing when its lifetime ends_. By immediately dereferencing that pointer to copy its value somewhere else, you leak memory because you're not keeping a copy of the pointer to properly `free()` it later. Your function returns a pointer, so store its result in a pointer. `free()` that pointer when you're finished using the allocated object. Please read more about dynamic allocation before continuing with this sort of code.

Comment: @2501 What do you mean by SSCCE? Self contained example? I thought that meant just adding an edit to the post. Sorry I am fairly new to stack overflow, could you clarify what you mean by this

Comment: Use the keyword *SSCCE* and perform an online search.

Comment: `For whatever reason, however, the list only saves the last node I read into it, and links the prev node pointer and the next node pointer to that last node, so if I try and iterate over the list, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.` Yes, of course it does. You're not updating either parameter to `node_new()` to tell it to put the new node in a different location on subsequent calls. So, it puts it in the same place as before. _ad infininitum_. This gets back to my last point. You need to store the resulting pointer of `node_new()`in a pointer, presumably `nodeNew`, not dereference both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
*nodeNew = *node_new(newTask);
```

To this:

```
nodeNew = node_new(newTask);
```

Your original code copies the (dereferenced) *value* returned by `node_new()` to the *value* at (dereference of) `*nodeNew`. Thus, the **pointer** `nodeNew` never gets updated with the **address** of the new node created by `node_new()`... so you keep overwriting the value at `*nodeNew` while passing its unchanging address to `add()`.

**And** you get a memory leak into the bargain. You are responsible for `free()`ing every pointer ever returned to you by `malloc()`. But here, for the same reason given above, you're not keeping copies of the returned pointers to enable this... just linking to `nodeNew` over and over again.

You need to update the pointer `nodeNew` with the location of, well, each new node, before passing it on to `add()`. Then you'll actually be linking *different* nodes, and at their original addresses, rather than copying them to the same address in a leaky fashion and linking it to itself, infinitely.

You also need to `free()` all memory that you have dynamically allocated once you're finished using it, e.g. through a sweep of the linked list in a 'destructor' function or at the end of your program. Otherwise you're leaking memory. This is a basic error and, even in cases where it doesn't stop a program from working, wastes users' RAM, which they rightly dislike!

I highly recommend studying pointers and dynamic allocation some more before continuing trying to write code like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this fixed it. Originally, I didn't think that was the issue, because I initialize values of an array of task_blocks in a similar manner, (task[i] = *some_function()) and that worked just fine. I'll go back and review pointers some more, as I clearly need to. Again, thanks for the help

Comment: @Nick Thanks for letting me know. Whenever an answer on SO helps you, please upvote, and mark the best one as accepted! As for your `task[]` assignment, it might well work, but if that `some_function()` is anything like `node_new()`, then it'll be leaking memory too. I'd advise checking that.